# How to print values in console in karate tests

Tags: rest, karate

I'm trying to print value on console but I don't see any value

**snippet of code**

```
And prepresp = response.event.txn_count
Then print 'count is : ',  response.event.txn_count
Then print 'count is : ',  prepresp
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your code seems to be missing with 'def' keyword for defining 'prepresp'

```
And def prepresp = response.event.txn_count 
Then print 'count is : ', response.event.txn_count 
Then print 'count is : ', prepresp
```

This should work

Comment: com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Expected to find an object with property ['EXPR$0'] in path $ but found 'net.minidev.json.JSONArray'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.
 at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.PropertyPathToken.evaluate(PropertyPathToken.java:69)
 at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.RootPathToken.evaluate(RootPathToken.java:62)
 at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:53)
 at com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:61

Comment: o/p from postman  

[
    {
        "EXPR$0": 479085608
    }
]

Scenario: Get count
  Given url 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  And request {body}
  When method POST
  Then status 200
  And mtlprepresp = response.EXPR$0
  Then print 'count is : ',  response.EXPR$0
  Then print 'count is : ',  mtlprepresp

Comment: @ShivaKrishna your response is an array so do this: `* def count = response[0].EXPR$0`

Comment: Thanks @Peter Thomas it worked

Also is they any reference on how to pass jwt in tests
can you pls let me know if there's any documentation on that

Comment: Done - Accepted
now pls any reference on how to pass jwt in tests

Comment: @ShivaKrishna here you go: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/jwt/jwt.feature

Answer (score 3):

You should use `karate.log(response)` for logging on the console.

Answer (score 1):

The print action should print to the HTML page which is provided in the console after the tests run.

Comment: can you give an example

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------
feature: classpath:mock/contract/payment-service.feature
scenarios:  1 | passed:  1 | failed:  0 | time: 0.1510
---------------------------------------------------------
HTML report: (paste into browser to view) | Karate version: 1.0.0
file:/home/username/git/karate/karate-demo/target/surefire-reports/mock.contract.payment-service.html
---------------------------------------------------------                                                          After the test runs you should see something like this in the console.

Comment: Take the file and paste it into a browser. This provides a little more verbose debugging for the tests. Another option is to run the test via the karate.jar UI. [link](https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Karate-UI)

Comment: Also the def keyword is missing in the And def prepresp = response.event.txn_count